# Насекомьи. Есть такое слово?

Tags: окказионализмы

Вроде должно быть, а поисковик выдаёт не словари, а весьма сомнительные источники.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, есть такое слово. Из классики:

> *...из дыры разорванных человечьих глаз выставятся **насекомьи** глазёнки, а старомодный фрак с золотыми пуговицами превратится в скорлупчатый
>   эпидермис.*
>
> (Андрей Белый, Начало века. На рубеже двух столетий, «Серия
>   литературных мемуаров»)
>
> *Но это была потешная **насекомья** смерть...* (из предисловия М. Елизарова к книге: Аркадий Гайдар, Обрез)
>   https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=oYm8AAAAQBAJ&pg=PP5&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&sig=ACfU3U3TD1VCoBmr8WEwBdMhZXCGMEaXTA&w=1280

Answer (score 3):

Вот орфографический словарь — уже авторитетный источник:
[http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&word=насекомий](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&word=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B9)
В множественном числе будет "*насекомьи*". Это прилагательное от слова "*насекомое*".

Answer (score 1):

Действительно, слово не находится в распространённых словарях. Но поиск в гугло-книгах показывает, что многие именитые писатели его использовали. Несколько лет назад вышла детская книга ["Насекомьи сказки"](https://fantlab.ru/edition167783). Слово звучит вполне естественно, голосую "за".